# c++ Qt, wait for second click

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt creator to make a simple drawing program in c++. I have a mouseevent, that should get the coordinates to the nearest point (dot) allready existing from the point where mouse was clicked, and put them to line starting point coordinates. Thats done. But now the event should wait for a second mouse click to get the nearest dot coordninates again and put them to end point of line. But instead it does not wait for the second input and puts the same first point for the line endpoint also.

How can I make mouseevent take two click inputs, not do everything right away? Is it even possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Moah" why did you delete your answer. It was correct.

Comment: Assuming you meant that for me, I had some site errors while trying to post. I think it's resolved now though, and reposted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make one event require two clicks (excluding, of course, the double click event). You can, however, establish a state within your application, where the first click starts the state and the second completes it. Pseudo-code to manage this:

```
// in your constructor:
StartingClickPoint = INVALID; // indicate that we have not entered our special state


// in your mouse event handler:
if (StartingClickPoint == INVALID) {
    // we're only now starting this state; we don't have enough information to complete it
    StartingClickPoint = CurrentClickPoint;
    return;
}
else {
    // complete the state handling and arm for the next pair of clicks
    EndingClickPoint = CurrentClickPoint;
    DoSomethingWithTheClickPoints();
    StartingClickPoint = INVALID; // reset for the next pair of clicks
}
```